# Creating an array that will display all the items I need

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get all the necessary information into one array, so for example all my tshirts would fall under the tshirt array

```
'tshirts' => [

]
```

so in that array I would like for all the product names that would fall under the tshirt category along with their price,
but the issue I'm having at the moment is that I'm only getting one piece of the data instead of everything.

So what I'm currently getting is this

```
'tshirts' => [
    'name' => 'tshirt 1'
]
```

instead of a list of all the tshirts in that category.

Here is my code

```
$products = Product::all();

$productArr = [];
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product[$product->category] => [
        'name' => $product->name
    ];
}

dd($productArr);
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, `$product[$product->category] => [` should be `$product[$product->category] = [`. Next up is the logic error, where you keep overwriting the data in the category. You need another set of brackets to *add* an item in each iteration: `$product[$product->category][] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$productArr` instead of `$product`.

```php
$products = Product::all();
$productArr = [];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productArr[$product->category][] = [
        'name' => $product->name
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you loop and find a specific category, you're overwriting the array for that category with a new array containing one item.

You need to *append* to it:

```
$productArr[$product->category][] = [
        'name' => $product->name
];
```

Also the `=>` is wrong, you need `=` here, and the name of your array is `$productArr`. `$product` is the source item from your loop!